# Network topology of dropout

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, graph-theory, dropout

So [dropout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_(neural_networks)) is a popular way to regularize neural networks by randomly removing nodes in the network. There are similar methods that remove edges, as well as [skip connections](https://theaisummer.com/skip-connections/#:%7E:text=Skip%20connections%20in%20deep%20architectures,gradient%20as%20we%20go%20backwards.) which introduce connections that skip layers of the network.

I am wondering whether there has been any topological explanation of why these methods work. The high-level explanation is that dropout introduces randomness and thus reduces overfitting, and that it smooths the loss landscape. But I am looking for something that rigorously shows the effect of new/deleted linkages on the loss function.

More specifically, backpropagation can quantify the effect of a single node/edge on the loss, so is there a way to use that knowledge to describe the effect of dropout?

Comment: "...backpropagation can quantify the effect of a single node/edge on the loss, so is there a way to use that knowledge to describe the effect of dropout?" Backprop can give the gradient of the loss w.r.t. a connection weight, or unit activation. At best, this gives a linear approximation of how the loss will react if you perturb the weight/activation from its current value by a small amount. It doesn't generally say what will happen if you set this value to zero. Not an answer, but just something to note

Comment: @user20160 Thanks! Using an Euler step, we can approximate the effect of setting the value to zero. Would this be a bad estimate in general?

Comment: Yes, that's the linear approximation I mentioned. If the function is nonlinear then approximation error increases as we move away from the initial point. So, this would only make sense if the initial value was already quite close to zero, which doesn't seem very useful. But, you really want to know the effect of clamping something to zero, why know just do it and calculate the actual loss?

Comment: @user20160 yes, that's true. I'm wondering how we can characterize this effect from a topological perspective though. E.g. if all weights are equal, then the more connected a node is, the more it should influence the loss. But I don't know what kind of tools are available to do this kind of analysis.